# How can I make Prolog speak?

Tags: prolog, text-to-speech

I have a list which holds some string values.

```
A = [John, goes, to, party].
```

How can I pass this text to speech?

Can any one tell me how to do text to speech conversion in prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the foreign language interface of your Prolog system to call an external API that does the speech synthesis. Prolog foreign language interface are not standard but Prolog system specific. Thus, without further details, is not difficult to give you more specific advise.

UPDATE: An alternative solution to the use of the foreign language interface is for the Prolog process to write the strings to standard output and to use a shell pipe to pass those strings to the Python process that reads those strings from standard input.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to connect it with python file.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I put A = [John, goes, to, party] kind of output as input to python?

Comment: See my updated answer for an alternative solution. But also note that some Prolog systems (e.g. YAP) provide an Python interface.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the cowsay pack.  pack_install(cowsay). Look at the 'add-ons' page on SWI-Prologs website.